# WebDAV folder is too slow to connect

Tags: nautilus, webdav, davfs2

I have a Box.com folder connected to my system using davfs2, and it takes a long time moving between folders everytime I use it with nautilus. I mount it to a local folder and everytime I click on a folder or a file, it takes a while to run, and sometimes it crashes nautilus.

Is there a way to download the whole directory as soon as the folder is mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing via Nautilus by typing 'dav://url.com/Folder' is as fast as can be, but mounting it is extremely slow.

Please create an Ubuntu One account and at the top of the bug below click on "This bug affects xx persons. Does this bug affect you?" and confirm "yes this bug affects me". This helps to give you a real answer/solution and not having to use `dav://`. On the right side you can also click "You are not directly subscribed to this bug's notifications.", and change if you want to be notified. This also adds to the "bug heat" (flame icon at the top).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/davfs2/+bug/185986